# iOS OC,How to convert RLMObject to NSDictionary,NSArray？

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

How to convert `RLMObject` to `NSDictionary`?
This is my code:

```
NSString *imei = [Utils getUUID];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"imei = %@",imei];

RLMResults<RLMRequestHeaderModel *> *models = [RLMRequestHeaderModel objectsWithPredicate:pred];

RLMRequestHeaderModel *header = models.firstObject;

// NSDictionary *headerDict = ...

return headerDict;
```

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this problem using this class. Very similar to the previous answer but in this case I added a special treatment for RLMArray objects or internal RLMObjects

```
@implementation RLMObject (NSDictionary)

- (NSDictionary*) dictionaryRepresentation{
    NSMutableDictionary *headerDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    RLMObjectSchema *schema = self.objectSchema;
    for (RLMProperty *property in schema.properties) {
        if([self[property.name] isKindOfClass:[RLMArray class]]){
            NSMutableArray *arrayObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            RLMArray *currentArray = self[property.name];
            NSInteger numElements = [currentArray count];
            for(int i = 0; i<numElements; i++){
                [arrayObjects addObject:[[currentArray objectAtIndex:i] dictionaryRepresentation]];
            }
            headerDictionary[property.name] = arrayObjects;
        }else if([self[property.name] isKindOfClass:[RLMObject class]]){
            RLMObject *currentElement = self[property.name];
            headerDictionary[property.name] = [currentElement dictionaryRepresentation];
        }else{
           headerDictionary[property.name] = self[property.name];
        }

    }
    return headerDictionary;
}

@end
```

Let me know if this can help you ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the key-value coding properties of Realm to extract all of the values to an `NSDictionary` pretty easily:

```
NSMutableDictionary *headerDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

RLMSchema *schema = header.objectSchema;
for (RLMProperty *property in schema.properties) {
   headerDictionary[property.name] = header[property.name];
}
```

Let me know if you need any additional clarification!